# OpenSearch Autocomplete with ASP.net

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, json

My website currently adds a custom Omnibox search engine to chrome using the following code:

ombnibox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <ShortName>Example </ShortName>
  <Description>Example Search</Description>
  <Url type="text/html" template="http://Example.com /search.aspx?searchVal=    {searchTerms}"></Url>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

My site master page includes:

```
<link type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Example" rel="search" href="/omnibox.xml" />
```

This is working great and users are brought to my search results page without any issues. I would like to integrate search suggestions into this custom search engine but I don't even know where to start. I have found a bunch of PHP examples returning JSON but I cannot find an example for ASP.net or an example that retrieves the result suggestions from a database.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this more and I was able to create a web-service that returns properly formatted JSON values to be used by the Omnibox **!!BUT!!** the Omnibox code requires that a "GET" request is called to access the web-service which is blocked by ASP.net by default. Once I overwrote the default settings for ASP.NET to allow GET requests, it would only allow me to return XML formatted values.

I am currently under the assumption that using the Omnibox type-ahead feature isn't an option unless I create a non-ASP.net web-service.

***UPDATE***

I was able to figure this out using an ASP.NET MVC WebAPI and the following code:

```
public object Get(string id)
    {
        List<ResultObject> resultValues = new List<ResultObject>();

        foreach (string val in ***SQLQUERYRESULTS***)
        {
            test singleResult = new ResultObject();
            singleResult.Name = val;
            singleResult.Description = "Server";
            singleResult.Url = "***CUSTOMURL***?ServerName=" + val;
            resultValues.Add(singleResult);

        }
        var entities = resultValues;
        var names = entities.Select(m => m.Name);
        var description = entities.Select(m => m.Description);
        var urls = entities.Select(m => m.Url);
        var entitiesJson = new object[] { id, names, description, urls };

        return entitiesJson;
    }
}


public class ResultObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following line to your xml file

```
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" method="get" template="http://www.domain.co.uk/autocomplete" />
```

and gets result in the following format:

```
["bm",["BMW","BMW X5","BMW X3","BMW 5 Series","BMW 1 Series","BMW 1 Series Cabriolet","BMW 3 Series","BMW Z4","BMW 3 Series Compact","BMW 116i"]]
```

Have a look at [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Supporting_search_suggestions_in_search_plugins)

I hope this help you.